# What is the expected value of the number of experiments required to obtain the first success?

Tags: expected-value, poisson-distribution, independence

In a simulation experiment, two independent observations $X_1$ and $X_2$ are generated from the Poisson distribution with mean 1. The experiment is said to be successful if $X_1 + X_2$ is odd. What is the expected value of the number of experiments required to obtain the first success?

(A) 2(1 + $e^{−2}$)

(B) 2/(1 − $e^{-2}$)

(C) 2/(1 − $e^{−4}$)

(D) 2(1 + $e^{−4}$)

I know that since $X_1$ an $X_2$ follows Poisson distribution with mean 1 $X_1+X_2$ will follow Poisson distribution with mean 2

The rest is totally blank. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: You are on the right track with $\mathsf{Pois}(2).$ I have revised my Answer also. Perhaps see [this Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068051/poisson-distribution-px-n-x-is-odd#:~:text=Assuming%20that%20is%20poisson%20distributed%2C%20the%20probability%20mass,.%20Thus%20if%20is%20odd%2C%20In%20closed%20form%3A) on another site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:** You are on the right track to look at $X \sim \mathsf{Pois}(2).$

You need to find $p = P(X \mathrm{\;is\;Odd}).$
Then the expected wait for the first odd $X,$ observing a sequence of its
simulated values, is $1/p$ by the geometric distribution.

- I claim that $p \approx  0.4908422$ (guessing it's good enough to sum
  probabilities of the first $101$ odd terms), so that $1/p \approx  2.037315.$
- Looking at the four answers provided, I find (C) evaluates to $2.037315.$
  So (C) must be the answer.

You should seek an analytic solution rather
than a strictly computational one.

Relevant R code:

```
k = seq(1, 201, by=2)
p = sum(dpois(k,2))
[1] 0.4908422
1/p
[1]  2.037315

2/(1-exp(-4))
[1] 2.037315
```